# Can't connect to cassandra cluster, but can connect to single node?

Tags: docker, cassandra, mesos, marathon, akka-persistence

I am facing some weird situation here while trying to connect a external Play Application to a cassandra cluster (which is running on a docker container over mesos).

The problem is:

If I only have a single Cassandra node, I can connect to it properly from the Play application. BUT, If I add a second node to it, I am not able to connect to any node anymore.

I am putting up the nodes as following:

**First node (SEED)**

```
{
    "id": "cassandra-seed",
    "constraints": [["hostname", "CLUSTER", "docker-sl-vm"]],
    "container": {
        "type": "DOCKER",
        "docker": {
            "image": "cassandra:latest",
            "network": "BRIDGE",
            "portMappings": [ {"containerPort": 9042,"protocol": "tcp"} ]
        }
    },
    "env": {
        "CASSANDRA_SEED_COUNT": "1"
    },
    "cpus": 0.5,
    "mem": 512.0,
    "instances": 1,
    "backoffSeconds": 1,
    "backoffFactor": 1.15,
    "maxLaunchDelaySeconds": 3600
}
```

At this point, I am able to connect playy app to cassandra-seed.

**CASSANDRA NODE2**

```
{
    "id": "cassandra",
    "constraints": [["hostname", "CLUSTER", "docker-sl-vm"]],
    "container": {
        "type": "DOCKER",
        "docker": {
            "image": "cassandra:latest",
            "network": "BRIDGE",
            "portMappings": [ {"containerPort": 9042,"protocol": "tcp"} ]
        }
    },
    "env": {
        "CASSANDRA_SEED_COUNT": "1",
        "CASSANDRA_SEEDS": "cassandra-seed.marathon.mesos"
    },
    "cpus": 0.5,
    "mem": 512.0,
    "instances": 1,
    "backoffSeconds": 1,
    "backoffFactor": 1.15,
    "maxLaunchDelaySeconds": 3600
}
```

After this node comes up, I can't connect to it nor to cassandra-seed.

**nodetool status** result:

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UJ  172.17.0.3  92.91 KB   256          ?       ccf83479-beed-44f5-9e36-6c997fd8855c  rack1
UN  172.17.0.2  96.96 KB   256          ?       1e42609d-ba3f-4c35-80c2-424a095b4db7  rack1
```

It looks like after the second node is up, cassandra isn't bound to the address, and the host stop seeing it. What should I do?